# @media screen is not working, whats wrong?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have the following code, which I am getting from a tutorial. 
When I run on Chrome, or Firefox, all the two lines are displaying no matter if I resize the window or not. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

#content-desktop {display: block;}
#content-mobile {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

#content-desktop {display: none;}
#content-mobile {display: block;}

</style>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


<div class="content-desktop">
This is the content that will display on DESKTOPS.
</div>

<div class="content-mobile">
This is the content that will display on MOBILE DEVICES.
</div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you're using `class="content-desktop"` and `class="content-mobile"` and your CSS is expecting `id` because you used `#content-desktop` and `#content-mobile`.

Secondly, you forgot to close your bracket.

In CSS, you need to use the dot `.` to select `class` and `#` to select `id`.

Try this :

```
.content-desktop {display: block;}
.content-mobile {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .content-desktop {display: none;}
   .content-mobile {display: block;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never closing the bracket opened here:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
```

Therefore, the entire `@media` rule is dropped by the parser. Simply close it where it should be closed (probably before `</style>`).

Answer (score 0):

You never closed the brackets, you're using # to target class you need to use . 
also you're div's were outside the body tag. Further more you need to have a query for the above scaling as well in this case. the following code is tested. you can run it directly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.desktop {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile{
      background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
    .mobile{
        display: none;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hide elements on different screen sizes</h2>

<div class="desktop">Show on desktop but hide on mobile.</div>
<div class="mobile">Show on Mobile but hide on desktop</div>


</body>
</html>
```